# How to add an int value to 'i' for each person in a multi-dimensional array every time they satisfy an if statement

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a weighted average based on how well each individual (who has their own array for 'name', 'gender', 'age' 'subject', etc) matches the criteria for the client.

eg.
If they study the right subject, `i +100`
else if they study a similar subject, `i +75`
else `i * 1`.

But I'm aiming for `i` to be updated for each candidate simultaneously. Feel free to tell me if I'm looking at this the wrong way or there is an easier way of doing this, more than happy to admit mistakes.

I wrote a bit of pseudo code for a simpler version, but I'm concerned that it doesn't fit the specification and would be a bit slow. Code below edited as suggested.

```php
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM data";            
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$candidates = array();                  
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {                          
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $candidates[] = $row;
  }
}


//Not sure if this next bit makes sense or doing it wrong.

foreach($candidates as $i => $value) {
if (in_array($cand_subject, $searched_subject))  {
  $i = $i + 1000;
}
elseif (in_array($cand_subject, $similar_subject)) {
  $i = $i + 800;
} else {
  $i = $i * 1;
}
```

Comment: How would you define a *similar subject*?

Comment: That would be defined by me and probably a series of if statments at the moment in order to get a minimum viable product and then update the array with those. Something like: if they are looking for a finance student, a similar student could be one studying accounting

Comment: You should show us what you tried instead of pseudocode. That way, we can pick up from where you went wrong and you can help in your mistakes and you can learn more.

Comment: Ok, will do. I'll update the code shortly, thank you.

Comment: Don't edit the key. It is used to identify an element. and should be unique. Not for storing purposes but for identification purposes. Like `$row[0]`;

Comment: Also, we cannot see where you defined `$searched_subject` and `$similar_subject`

Comment: The defined value for the $searched_subject and the $similar_subject are defined by the clientss search and not done yet.

Comment: The answer looks good, much better than what i wrote, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want something like this (explained everything in comments)

```php
<?php 
$pages_array = array( // intiate an array
     array( // another array inside an array to define array of objects.
         'name' => 'James', 
         'skills' => array("ai","php") //another array for array of strings
     ),

     array( // same here
         'name' => 'ben',
         'skills' => array('C#', 'react', 'flutter')
     )
);
foreach ($pages_array as $key => $value) { // for each of the array's
    $score = 0;
    if (in_array("ai", $value["skills"])) { // note $value["skills"] is an array. So we check if the array has the string "ai"
        $score = 100;
    }else{
        $score = 75;
    }
    $value["score"] = $score; // add a field score into the array and put the value.
}
?>
```

This is same as you mentioned the puesdo code in your question.